# How does FileVault 2 recovery key stored in iCloud work?

Tags: icloud, encryption, recovery

When requested during the full disk encryption process, one option is to store the recovery key in your iCloud account.

I stored mine in iCloud, but frankly I'm confused as when I look at the drive contents I see NO files even indicating a recovery key.

So what exactly is happening?  Also, how is this used during the recovery process?

Also, if you put your recovery key in iCloud, how is more than one device handled (i.e. macbooks)?

Comment: The first part of your question is  rather opinion based. Do you trust Apple?

Comment: True, but being a Mac Newbie, I'm not in full understanding of how the iCloud option really works.

Comment: So maybe you should ask that instead?

Comment: Even if the recovery key is accessible via iCloud Drive (would be extremely surprised if it was) and not just stored somewhere on Apple's server attached to your overall iCloud account, it would be a hidden file. Hidden files are not visible in Finder or really anywhere on your Mac, unless you take specific actions to [enable viewing them](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/). (The only exception is in Terminal, if you use `ls -a` instead of just `ls` to list a directory's contents.)

Answer (score 1):

The recovery key absolutely isn’t stored locally by Apple, so you either need a safe place to store it where you won’t lose it or Apple will help store it for you to recover later when you choose to unlock the Mac by reading the key from iCloud.

- in a nutshell, your iCloud password gets you your key back instead of you needing to choose where to store it (paper in a safe, 1Password app, word document, under the keyboard, screen capture of the image of your key on screen, etc...)

Comment: Hey @bmike, I'm also interested in this. So if I ever need it, my Mac will prompt me for my iCloud password?

Comment: I’m not sure how to answer your question @ralphjsmit would you ask it on the site and link to my answer so we can follow the discussion.